# (Co)Variance of a random matrix

Tags: variance, covariance, random-matrix, random-vector

The expected value $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}]$ of a random vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ is the vector of the expected values of each individual random variable $\mathbf{x}$ contains.

The (variance-)covariance matrix $\text{Var}[\mathbf{x}]$ of a random vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix defined by
$$
\text{Var}[\mathbf{x}] = \mathbb{E}\left[
    (\mathbf{x} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}]) \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}])^T
\right].
$$

For a suitable constant matrix $\mathbf{A}$ the identity
$$\text{Var}[ \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} ] = \mathbf{A} \text{Var}[\mathbf{x}] \mathbf{A}^T$$
holds.

My questions are: Is there a common concept of a (variance-)covariance »matrix« $\text{Var}[\mathbf{X}]$ of a random *matrix* $\mathbf{X}$ (instead of just a random vector)? If so: Are there some simple identities like
$$\text{Var}[ \dots \mathbf{X} \dots ] = \dots \text{Var}[\mathbf{X}] \dots \ ?$$
For my case it would also suffice if there exists just a common concept of a »plain« variance matrix which would for example just collect the individual variances of the contained random variables (discarding the covariance values).

I would very much appreciate references to introductory material.

Comment: Diag(var(vec(X))) comes to mind.

Comment: An $m\times n$ matrix is just an $mn$-vector written in a special way.  Thus, everything you know about vectors applies.

Comment: @whuber How would you interpret a random matrix $\mathbf{X}$ such that $\text{Var}[\mathbf{AX}]$ resolves like in my question stated above? Just linearizing it by replacing it with $\text{vec}[\mathbf{X}]$ does not work because $\mathbf{A\text{vec}[\mathbf{X}]}$ is not a legal matrix-vector product.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no unified theory. However, if you defined the matrix variance in a fashion similar to vectors, $\text{Var}[\mathbf{M}] = \mathbb{E}\left[
    (\mathbf{M} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{M}]) \cdot (\mathbf{M} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{M}])^T
\right],$ you might get some nice properties out of it... If there is something developed as beautiful as the theory for vectors, I would be very curious about any references. Thanks.

Comment: $AX,$ when $A$ and $X$ are considered vectors, is the dot product of $A^\prime$ and $X.$  There's no problem manipulating it.  The theory is perfectly standard, @stans.  The only variations concern how one *represents* $X$ as a vector: whether to leave it in matrix form, to unravel it row by row, or unravel it column by column.